# How do i find the unique number in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have no idea why this isn't working. The solution was basically the exact opposite of mine, yet that one somehow worked (it examined the first two indexes instead of the last two). Am I missing something?

```js
function findUniq(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return arr.slice(-2) === arr.pop() ? arr.shift() : arr.pop();
}

console.log(findUniq([0, 1, 0])); // 0, and arr is [0]
```

Comment: I've changed the slice(-2) into slice(-2, -1). But for some reason, arr is now [0]. Do you know why?

Comment: Because [*pop*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is removing elements from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

sorts the array to be:

```
[0, 0, 1]
```

In the return expression:

```
arr.slice(-2) === arr.pop()
```

resolves as follows:

```
arr.slice(-2)
```

returns an array that is a shallow copy of the last two elements of the array. Then

```
arr.pop()
```

removes the last element from the array and returns its value, so the array is now `[0, 0]` and the expression resolves to:

```
[0, 1] === 1
```

which is false. Strict comparison of `arr.slice(...)` to anything will always be false, even `arr.slice(-2) === arr.slice(-2)` is false as it compares two different objects, although they have the same elements with the same values.

So the false branch of the [conditional operator `?:`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-conditional-operator) expression is executed:

```
arr.pop();
```

resolves to:

```
[0, 0].pop()
```

which removes and returns the last element from *arr* so returns `0` and *arr* is now `[0]`.

Also see:

1. [MDN: Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
2. [MDN: Array.prototype.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Comment: Wow, thank you for making me realise my mistake! I appreciate the time you took just to help me :)

Comment: @asoupling You can mark this answer as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark if this helped you :D